# Casting Bigdecimal to Integer

Tags: java, casting

i am facing exception in the line

```
int cdStatus = ((Integer)vecColumns.elementAt(1)).intValue();


 00000050 CommerceSrvr  E com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget executeCommand CMN0420E: 
 The following command exception has occurred during processing: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.lang.Integer". 
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.lang.Integer
    at com.ibm.commerce.promotion.facade.server.commands.ValidateUniquePromotionCodesTaskCmdImpl.verifyPromotionCodes(ValidateUniquePromotionCodesTaskCmdImpl.java:137)
    at com.ibm.commerce.promotion.facade.server.commands.ValidateUniquePromotionCodesTaskCmdImpl.performExecute(ValidateUniquePromotionCodesTaskCmdImpl.java:84)
```

Here veColumn is a Vector and the elementAt(1) is an coloumn in the database and of type smallInt in the database side. I am not sure how big decimal come into this picture?

Answer (score 2):

The element you're pulling from the array has the type BigDecimal. You can't cast a BigDecimal to an Integer. Replace the cast to Integer with a cast to BigDecimal and it should work.

Comment: The query executed is   "select pcp.code, pcu.status from px_cdusage pcu, px_cdpool pcp where pcu.px_cdpool_id = pcp.px_cdpool_id and pcp.usagetype = 0 and pcp.code in ( select code from ordpromocd where orders_id =8443468)"     and the pcu.status is in scene here which shows SMALLINT as its type on oracle. Please refer the link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.database.doc/database/px_cdusage.htm

Comment: That is the database type. It doesn't have to reflect the type it becomes in Java. Now this part of the exception tells me that you've got a BigDecimal and you're trying to cast it to an Integer. You could also look at the contents of `vecColumns` with a debugger and see for yourself.
`The following command exception has occurred during processing: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.lang.Integer".`

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the unusual behavior is that even though the PX_CDUSAGE defines the column as SMALLINT, it is indeed mapped as a NUMBER(38) in an Oracle database, which, in turn, is represented as a BigDecimal Java object, which explains why `vecColumn.elementAt(1)` contains a `BigDecimal` instead of the expected `Integer`.

further details can be found here: [Error description](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR49896)

Now, as a solution, a simple cast to BigDecimal instead of Integer to avoid the ClassCastException, as mpkorstanje correctly pointed out, but since this seems like code you cannot alter, I'd advise to check the indicated fix in the link of disabling the check. It might be the only possible solution without changing the column type.

Comment: thank you very much mpkorstanje and fsb. Actually the Vendor who provided this code gave a APAR to fix this. They might be changed the code after installing tyis APAR.